# How does game trade work?

Tags: steam

I have spare copies of some games bought in various past 4-pack offers.

[image: Steam items]

How can I trade one of them with another user? If I click an item I don't see any *Trade* button, but only gift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your friends list, right click a user and press "Invite to trade."  In there, you'll be able to send unused copies of games and items from several supported games.  Trading supports game copies for game items and items between different games, with no real limits.

At the moment, the supported games for item trading are:

- Team Fortress 2 items (hats, scrap metal, weapons, crates, keys, etc.)
- Portal 2 (cosmetics)
- Spiral Knights (materials, weapons/cosmetics/armor that are unbounded, CE; crystal energy and crowns)
- DotA 2 (consumables, couriers, announcers, gear, backgrounds, etc.)
- Steam (gifts, backgrounds, cards, emoticons, gems, etc.)

Comment: TF2 is F2P, how can you trade that?

Comment: @JeffreyLin While it probably is possible to trade premium copies of TF2 for people who had extra copies before it went F2P, the list is actually of the supported games for **item trading**

Comment: @DaveMcCelland But if you are gifting TF2, wouldn't an Upgrade to Premium gift be cheaper?

Comment: @JeffreyLin I have no idea if premium is even tradable. I was just hypothesizing about a way it could be possible as a sidenote in my response.

Comment: Premium Upgrade is indeed tradable, it costs around $5. (https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Upgrade_to_Premium_Gift)

Answer (score 5):

From [the Steam FAQ article](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6748-ETSG-5417):

> Any game you’ve purchased from the store as a gift, or received as an Extra Copy, can be traded to other users. They can be used to trade for other Gifts, or for items in Team Fortress 2 or Spiral Knights. We’ve added a new checkout option to the Store when purchasing a gift so you can save it for trading or sending later, to support users who want to save games for trade fodder.

Additionally

> Only gifts that are purchased on trusted accounts can be traded immediately; otherwise there is a 90-day cool down before the gift can be traded. Any account that has made any valid purchase from the Steam Store more than 90 days ago is considered trusted. This is to ensure that all games traded are valuable, and help prevent fraudulent purchases for the purpose of trades.

It might be the case that you fall into that "non-trusted account" group.